# Required Help in InApp Purchases Flutter using revenue cat

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription, revenuecat

Can Some one explain inValidProduct receipt Error why does it occurr In ios in sandbox and TestFlight testing payments this happen when I purchase same plan using same sandbox account currently I can purchase one plan only with one sandbox account, lets suppose if I purchased Monthly subscription Iam not able to purchase same plan monthly subscription even after expiry I'm getting this error.
Can't figure out why this happening.

PlatformException(8, The receipt is not valid. The purchased product was missing in the receipt. This is typically due to a bug in StoreKit., {userCancelled: false, underlyingErrorMessage: The purchased product was missing in the receipt. This is typically due to a bug in StoreKit., message: The receipt is not valid. The purchased product was missing in the receipt. This is typically due to a bug in StoreKit., readableErrorCode: INVALID_RECEIPT, code: 8, readable_error_code: INVALID_RECEIPT}, null)

I have tried multiple accounts but the issue is same only one purchase happen successfully.